# Why do I get shared Ids with JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I've a question about JPA and Inheritance (EclipseLink) :

For a school project, I've created an abstract class : HumanEntity 
and different subclasses which implement it.

The abstract class:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class HumanEntity implements IHuman{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
protected long      id;

@Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
protected String    firstName;

@Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
protected String    lastName;

protected LocalDate birthDate;

protected HumanEntity(){

}

@Override
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

@Override
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

@Override
public LocalDate getBirthDate() {
    return birthDate;
}
```

}

A subclass example :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ACTOR")
public class ActorEntity extends HumanEntity{

protected ActorEntity(){}

protected ActorEntity(ActorBuilder actorBuilder){
    this.firstName  = actorBuilder.getFirstName();
    this.lastName = actorBuilder.getLastName();
    this.birthDate  = actorBuilder.getBirthDate();
}
```

}

When I run the the project : 
-> Ids are shared for every subclasses then I have

In the Actor Table : 
1 -> ....
3 -> ....

In the director table : 
2 -> ....

How can I create a different Id for every subclasses but with a protected (shared) Id in my code ?

Another little question EclipseLink ,or JPA always create a sequence table but i dont know what is it used for ? can I delete it ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All objects that are of type `HumanEntity` or subclasses are instances of `HumanEntity`, hence the id's need to be consistent, and hence from the same "group" of ids.

You CANNOT have say id 1 for an `Actor` **and** id 1 for a `Director` since they are both `HumanEntity`, and you need to uniquely identify a `HumanEntity`. i.e Actor#1 is also HumanEntity#1. So you cannot also have Director#1 since that would also be HumanEntity#1!

If you want to have id's like those then you would need to change your inheritance structure.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it would be interesting which database platform you are using. As you mentioned a school project I assume it is either PostgreSQL or MySQL?!

The ID's values are based on the strategy (see [GenerationType](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/GenerationType.html)) that is used along with the `@GeneratedValue` annotation. If you don't specify any specific strategy for a `@GeneratedValue`-field, the default strategy should be `javax.persistence.GenerationType.AUTO` according to the [JPA JavaDoc of GeneratedValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html). However EclipseLink seems to use `javax.persistence.GenerationType.TABLE` according to their [documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/Ids/GeneratedValue):

> GenerationType:
>   The strategy of the GeneratedValue is defined by the GenerationType enumerated type. The strategy defines how the id value should be generated on the database. By default, EclipseLink chooses the TABLE strategy using a table named SEQUENCE, with SEQ_NAME and SEQ_COUNT columns, with allocationSize of 50 and pkColumnValue of SEQ_GEN. If SEQUENCE is used the default database sequence used is named SEQ_GEN_SEQUENCE with an allocationSize of 50.

This basically means that EclipseLink will use a non business database table `SEQUENCE` to lookup the next values. Furthermore it will use the `SEQ_GEN` row of this table for generation of all default generated values. That is all entities will share a common pool of generated values by default. I don't have a DMBS at hand right now but looking into this table will probably give you more insights on the used values.

If you want to use a different strategy or another table for generation you should take a look at the JavaDoc of [TableGenerator](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/TableGenerator.html) and [SequenceGenerator](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html). That way you could create a separate sequence for each subclass.

I think the above already answered your question regarding the sequence table (at least I hope so). So I'd rather not delete it...